# While Loop causes file to crash

Tags: c++, while-loop, crash

I am writing a code for a programming class that takes in a list of years and then displays whether or not they are leap years or not. When I run the code, after entering a list of years and hitting return, the file crashes.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <vector>

    int main(void)
    {
        std::vector<int> years;
        int c = 0;
        int i;
        int x = 1;

        std::cout<< "Enter a space separated list of years (enter a negative number to stop)"<<std::endl;

        while(x>0)
        {
            if(x<=0)
            {
                break;
            }
            std::cin>> x;
            years[c] = x;
            c++;
        }

        for(i=0; i<=years.size(); i++)
        {
            if((years[i] % 4 == 0 && years[i] % 100 != 0) || (years[i] % 400 == 0))
            {
                 std::cout<< years[i] << " is a leap year" << std::endl;
            }else{std::cout<< years[i] << " is not a leap year" << std::endl;}
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `for(i=0; i<=years.size(); i++)` -- See anything wrong with that line, things like going out-of-bounds on the last iteration?

Comment: Also, instead of `years[c]`, try `years.at(c)`.  Instead of `if ((years[i]` try `if (years.at(i)`.  Then the issue will show itself boldly to you in the form of an `out_of_range` exception instead of just a crash.

Comment: Isn’t the if(x<=0) block a little redundant since the value of x is evaluated by the while loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Problem 1

The declaration of `years` creates an empty vector. For that reason, the line

```
years[c] = x;
```

is not right. It accesses `years` using out of bounds indices. Use

```
years.push_back(x);
```

#### Problem 2

The logic for reading the data and detecting that it's time to stop is wrong.

```
std::cin>> x;
years[c] = x;
```

suffers from two problems.

1. It does not check whether the value of `x` is greater than 0 before adding it to `years`.
2. It does not check whether the reading of data to `x` was successful. It assumes that it is successful.

Change the reading code to:

```
while(std::cin >> x)
{
   if(x<=0)
   {
      break;
   }

   years.push_back(x);
}
```

You cam combine the checks into the conditional of the `while` statement.

```
while ( (std::cin >> x) && ( x > 0 ) )
{
   years.push_back(x);
}
```

#### Problem 3

You are writing one more item than what `years` holds when you use `i <= years.size()` in the loop. It needs to be `i < years.size()`.

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < years.size(); i++)
{
   if((years[i] % 4 == 0 && years[i] % 100 != 0) || (years[i] % 400 == 0))
   {
      std::cout<< years[i] << " is a leap year" << std::endl;
   }
   else
   {
      std::cout<< years[i] << " is not a leap year" << std::endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that, the code now runs. However it gives some interesting results. This is what happens: Enter a space separated list of years (enter a negative number to stop)
1812 1816 2005 -1
1812 is a leap year
1816 is a leap year
2005 is not a leap year
-1 is not a leap year
1165250592 is a leap year        I am uncertain where the random number at the end came from

Comment: Awesome thank you for the updated answer, solved my issue of it reading -1 as an input and saying its not a leap year.

Answer (score 0):

To complement R Sahu's answer on the first part, your `for` loop indexing at the bottom is incorrect. You are trying to access one past the end of the allocated `vector` array, which is why you are getting a random number and a random output. (More technically, it is causing undefined behavior.)

This is your code before:

```
for(i=0; i<=years.size(); i++)
{
    if((years[i] % 4 == 0 && years[i] % 100 != 0) || (years[i] % 400 == 0))
    {
       std::cout<< years[i] << " is a leap year" << std::endl;
    } else {
       std::cout<< years[i] << " is not a leap year" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The `<=` in the conditional has the loop iterate from 0 until `years.size()`, but the indexes you can access are 0 until `years.size()-1`. To fix this, do the following:

```
for(i=0; i<years.size(); i++)
{
    if((years[i] % 4 == 0 && years[i] % 100 != 0) || (years[i] % 400 == 0))
    {
       std::cout<< years[i] << " is a leap year" << std::endl;
    } else {
       std::cout<< years[i] << " is not a leap year" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Now it should stop at -1.